# Что такое непрерывная интеграция?

Tags: agile, teamcity, git-flow, непрерывная-интеграция

Проблема: Последнее вливание ветки разработчика в ветку `develop` занял три дня, при этом пришлось разрулить порядка 100 конфликтов.

Условия: В динамическом проекте 3 разработчика и мы работаем по [Git Flow](http://habrahabr.ru/post/106912/). Разработчики создают свою ветку от ветки `develop`, а через некоторое время (от 3 дней до 3 недель, в зависимости от сложности задачи) вливают в неё изменения. Возможны глобальные и перекрестные изменения.

**Задача: минимизировать затраты времени на интеграцию изменений разработчиков в ветку `develop`.**

Из опробованных средств было соглашение о стремлении к частому вливанию изменений в `develop`. Это, определенно, не помогло. По идее сервер непрерывной интеграции должен решать эту проблему, но я не могу понять каким образом. В данный момент у нас есть `TeamCity`, который я развернул для того чтобы он запускал тесты при каждом коммите. И я полагаю что всё-таки не это является основной обязанностью сервера непрерывной интеграции :)

Если непрерывная интеграция подразумевает постоянный merge изменений в `develop`, то мне становится недоступной ситуация когда я могу в отдельной ветке поломать часть функционала, заменив в течении недели на новый. Если я сливаю изменения с `develop` моя текущая работа влияет на работу другого разработчика (или это даже плюс?). Но даже если делать вливание в `develop` только когда все тесты проходят, не думаю что это решит проблему: достаточно крупное изменение будет означать может только один коммит в пару дней (*upd поправка: так может случиться с учетом если примем решение коммитить только валидный код, а сложное изменение ломает функционал надолго*).

Я хочу услышать как в ваших проектах организована работа с сервером непрерывной интеграции. Как вы бы организовали нашу работу исходя из текущих условий?

Comment: А как насчет сделать модульную архитектуру?

Comment: @korytoff Микросервисы на подходе, но данная проблема будет так или иначе существовать когда в проекте >1 разработчика.

Comment: Да никак. Проблемы с мерджами всегда будут в команде, где больше 1 человека.

Comment: @Suvitruf поэтому надо построить рабочий процесс таким образом чтобы время уходящее на интеграцию было минимальным.

Comment: @Onedev.Link это только возможно, если пушиться изменения будут постоянно, каждые 5 минут, и в одну ветку. Если люди в разных ветках, то это уже геморой. А если в момент, когда вы мерджите свою ветку с мастер веткой, кто-то успеет замерджить своё, то у вас настанет ад )

Comment: "Если непрерывная интеграция подразумевает постоянный merge изменений" - не подразумевает. Это разные задачи с разными целями

Comment: Суд по вашему описанию, у вас не git flow, а github flow (главная ветка + фича бранчи). git flow подразумевает еще наличие мастер, релиз, фича и хотфикс веток.

Comment: @andreycha верно, просто мы ещё не релизнулись :)

Comment: Поздравляю, ваш вопрос попал в ежеденедельную рассылку StackOverflow на русском!

Comment: "Какую задачу решает сервер непрерывной интеграции?" — это уже тема отдельного вопроса. Сервер решает ту задачу, которую вы ему поставите. У него нет интеллекта и свободной воли, чтобы решать какую-то свою задачу.

Comment: @NickVolynkin заслуженно :) Напиши ответ в тему наименования тестов, интересно что напишешь)

Comment: @NickVolynkin буду ждать :)

Comment: Вы спрашивали «Что такое непрерывная интеграция»,  а в итоге приняли ответ на «Что такое сервер непрерывной интеграции». Ответ же от другого вопроса.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Автор раскрыл основную цель непрерывной интеграции: раннее нахождение  ошибок вне merge-конфликтов. Все ответы хорошие, но именно его ответ зажег во мне слово Эврика!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Непрерывная Интеграция - это процесс объединения копий нескольких разработчиков в общую ветвь несколько раз в день.

- [Continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)
- [Trunk (software)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trunk_(software))

Хотя распределенные системы контроля версий позволяют не иметь центрального репозитория, именно из-за наличия общих ветвей, объединяющих изменения, основной компонент инфраструктуры непрерывной интеграции это прежде всего центральный репозиторий, развернутый на сервере (Github, Bitbucket, Gitlab).

В дополнение к этому, часто применяются серверы Continuous Integration, основная функция которых - осуществлять сборку и проверку проекта, например TeamCity.

Сервер Continuous Integration никак не поможет с техническими конфликтами системы контроля версий, но он может выявить часть логических конфликтов, например - некомпилирующийся проект, или поломанный тест даже после бесконфликтного с точки зрения системы контроля версий слияния.

В некоторый случаях сервер CI может выявить конфликты слияния, например - с помощью функции [Automatic Merge в TeamCity](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Automatic+Merge) (начиная с версии 8.1).

Незаменимая вещь - отчет сборке, включая результаты автоматических тестов на каждую фиксацию изменения в Trunk, а так же в других опубликованных ветвях. Это позволяет увидеть, если кто-то влил изменения, ломающие тест.

У нас собираются все опубликованные feature-ветви, поэтому можно даже отследить, как поломанный неделю назад в чьей-то ветке тест мигрировал в trunk, и попросить этого разработчика срочно пофиксить тест.

Проблемы объединения изменений возникают, когда разработчик слишком долго не объединял изменения, и сильно "разломал" свою ветвь. При этом проблема больше не в том, что разработчик не публиковал изменения, которые еще не готовы, а в том, что он не "подливал" себе чужие изменения. Не случайно идеология Git - Pull, don't push. Тех, кто делает только push и редко делает pull даже называли "пушистиками" в русском сообществе программистов.

Небольшой пример - я взялся рефакторить некоторый класс A, удалил из него публичный метод GetX, и заменил в 10 местах использование этого метода на другой, GetY.

Предположим, что никто из разработчиков в своих ветвях не пытается вносить изменения в класс A. Это хорошо, потому что даже если мои изменения затронули 10 мест по всему решению, Git имеет шанс разрулить конфликты этих 10 файлов. Кто-то редактировал некоторые из этих файлов, но не трогал ту строку, где вы скоро замените GetX на GetY.

Зато один из разработчиков привнес новое использование публичного метода GetX, потому что он не знал, что этого метода уже как бы нет, и уже интегрировал это изменение в Trunk. Это уже настоящий конфликт, который Git никогда не сможет разрулить. Мало того - Git может и не сообщить об этом логическом конфликте, потому что с точки зрения контроля версий файлов конфликта нет! Этот конфликт обнаружится на этапе компиляции, а некоторые другие логические конфликты и на этапе компиляции не обнаруживаются, и здесь становится ясна роль сервера CI, который выдаст отчет о тестах.

Так вот - если вы подливаете себе новые изменения других разработчиков часто, то вы тут же обнаружите этот конфликт, и тут же в своей ветке замените этот GetX на GetY, поговорите с другими, чтобы они по возможности не делали этого, и все окей - продолжайте дальше "ломать".

Еще один момент - компилируете ли вы перед тем, как сделать merge своей ветви в trunk? А что, сделали pull прямо перед push, и все окей, гит доволен. Все сделали pull, и все ругаются, что у них не собирается проект.

Вот для этого и нужен сервер Continuous Integration, в который вы можете опубликовать свою ветвь, сделать pull request, увидеть что сборка прошла, потом уже делаете merge.

У нас TeamCity шлет письма всем разработчикам, если не прошел билд, или упали тесты. Это очень помогает: сам не заметишь - другие тут же сообщат. Поэтому публикуйте свои ветви, и настройте TeamCity чтобы он собирал буквально все, и гонял по возможности тесты. У нас на каждый коммит гоняются только некоторый набор тестов, так, чтобы билд укладывался в 7 минут примерно. Ночью на транке тестируется билд с полным набором тестов, включая базу данных - это несколько часов.

Есть и несколько других методов, как можно уменьшить количество конфликтов.

Во-первых, постарайтесь разбить задачу на мелкие шаги, которые меняют решение поэтапно. Иногда изменение реализации можно сделать отдельно от изменения API. В первую очередь идут изменения, которые затрагивают API классов, потому что из этих изменений возникает большинство конфликтов. Предупредите других о таких изменениях во всеуслышание, согласуйте и как можно быстрее добейтесь объединения таких изменений, потом убедитесь, что все сделали pull этих ваших изменений.

Здесь помогает утренний скрам, так как другие могут вовремя узнать о том, что вы планируете делать, и посоветовать, как обеспечить "бесконфликтность".

Иногда можно реализовать изменение так, что новая фича, даже будучи не до конца реализованной, не поломает приложения. Например - у нас с десяток интеграций с однотипными партнерами, и добавление партнера - это два-четыре месяца. Никто не ныряет в бранч - фича просто присутствует в коде в отключенном на уровне конфигурации режиме. Первый этап, который подразумевает некоторый рефакторинг API, добавление какого-то базового класса, каких-то значений в справочники - производится по возможности быстро, и интегрируется в trunk, возможно это даже будет некий аврал, но такие вещи делаются задолго до следующего релиза. После этого можно перейти к постоянной интеграции, и спокойно "пилить" хоть год.

Другой вариант - если фича, ради которой разработчики уходят в свой бранч на неделю, затрагивает публичные интерфейсы существующих классов, то можно выделить задачу по изменению API в отдельный бранч, интегрировать его часто, и в основном бранче фичи подливать себе эти изменения так же, как его подливают себе остальные. Хорошо что Git позволяет практически мгновенно переключаться между ветвями.

У нас предусмотрены ветки обслуживания релизов.
Например - все основные изменения интегрируются в транк часто, а в ветку релиза ничего никогда не интегрируется. Там делаются только небольшие, точечные изменения, направленные на устранение критических ошибок. Никакого форматирования кода, никакого рефакторинга. Все эти изменения подливаются в trunk сразу же, и уже там находится лучшее решение, исправляющее ошибку более обстоятельно для следующего релиза. Это позволяет избежать конфликтов интеграции этих ветвей практически полностью.

Естественно, есть и неотъемлемые свойства самого проекта, которые могут косвенно влиять на количество конфликтов - это принципы [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), о которых уже упомянули в других ответах, при нарушении которых приходится делать изменения сразу в нескольких местах.

Comment: Вау, я планировал сам ответить на свой вопрос после того как досконально разберусь в теме, но ваш ответ отбил в этом необходимость. Я всё понял, введение в тему просто отличное. Через пару недель ждите бонус к репутации на этом ответе :)

Answer (score 45):

Процитирую принципы из книги *«Непрерывная Интеграция», Пол М. Дюваль, Стивен Матиас, Эндрю Гловер*. Принципы в качестве заголовоков, текст — мои собственные комментарии.

## 1. Передавайте код часто

Это означает, что инфраструктура должна позволять делать частые коммиты и частые мержи в основную ветку, а разработчик должен пользоваться этой возможностью.

Хорошо, когда разработчик может взять коммит с небольшими изменениями и на этом коммите запустить функциональные и интеграционные тесты. Если где-то есть ошибка, он заметит ее сразу же. При этом юнит-тестов может быть недостаточно, т.к. код может отлично отрабатывать в изолированном окружении, но сломается где-то выше, на уровне интеграции с другими компонентами. Чем более сложен программный продукт, тем интеграция сложнее и тем важнее это требование.

Для этого нужна СDCI-инфраструктура, которая позволяет на каждом коммите не только проводить юнит-тесты, но и создавать приближенное к боевому окружение, на котором можно проводить тесты — как автоматические, так и ручные.

Ещё один аспект — это одна ветка на одну фичу. Чем меньшими порциями вносятся изменения, тем легче их отслеживать.

> достаточно крупное изменение будет означать может только один коммит в пару дней.
>
> через некоторое время (от 3 дней до 3 недель, в зависимости от сложности задачи) вливают в неё изменения

Над чем здесь можно работать:

- Фичи меньшего размера. 3 недели это достаточно долго.
- Более частые коммиты. Коммит != фича. (Я вообще воспринимаю коммиты как сохраненки в опасной стрелялке и делаю коммит перед каждой дверью в темном углу).
- Чтобы любой промежуточный коммит можно было запустить в псевдо-боевом окружении и прогнать все тесты, включая интеграционные.

## 2. Не передавайте сбойный код

Тут всё достаточно просто. Если регрессионная проверка показывает, что новые изменения вносят баг, эти изменения не нужно сливать в `dev`. Вроде бы очевидно, но очень неосмотрительно будет предполагать, что 1) все тесты точно пройдены и 2) если они не пройдены, то разработчик не будет сливать свою ветку.

Система должна явным образом заставлять проходить все тесты и запрещать передачу сбойного кода. Все системы CI также умеют оповещать разработчика о неуспешном построении.

> Если я сливаю изменения с develop моя текущая работа влияет на работу другого разработчика (или это даже плюс?)

Не то чтобы плюс или минус, просто реальность. Подумайте о том, чтобы сливать develop и текущую фичу в каком-то отдельном месте. Возможно, для тестирования интеграции вам понадобится слить сразу несколько фич от разных разработчиков. Либо, если интеграция не на уровне кода, а на уровне отдельных компонент (например, вы пишете сервер, а коллега пишет клиент), то поднимайте полное окружение, в котором компоненты будут построены из ваших веток с фичами.

Только когда вы убедились, что в тестовой ветке интеграция успешна, сливайте результат в develop.

## 3. Ликвидируйте проблемы построения немедленно

Чинить ошибки построения — очень приоритетная задача. Если где-то сломался скрипт построения, или упал сервер интеграции, или устарели тесты — нужно идти и чинить. Такое вот ограничение непрерывной интеграции.

Если построение выполняется правильно, но ошибки есть в коде — та же ситуация. Задача не считается выполненной, пока не выполнены все проверки и не проведена успешная интеграция (как слияние в dev, так и развертывание на боевом окружении).

## 4. Пишите автоматизированные проверки разработки

Автоматизированные проверки (тесты) требуют человеческих ресурсов только на создание и поддержку, но не на проведение. Поэтому вы сможете проводить их сколь угодно часто (а нужно часто, см. пункт 1). Чем чаще проводятся проверки, тем быстрее обнаруживаются ошибки и тем ниже общая стоимость каждой проверки.

Мануальные проверки тоже можно автоматизировать в части управления. Если какая-то часть системы требует ручного тестирования, возможным решением будет при запуске автоматизированного построения создавать задачу на ручное — либо в системе управления тестированием, либо в трекере задач.

Отчет в системе управления тестированием выглядит примерно так  (это testrail):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Автоматизированные проверки — это не только функциональные тесты в каком-нибудь xUnit и не обязательно каждая проверка отвечает на вопрос "да/нет". Можно автоматизировать и производить:

1. Построение под все платформы, для которых вы производите свой продукт. Включает в себя создание установочных пакетов и их успешную установку через стандартные механизмы распространения (Google Play, `.msi/.exe`, репозиторий с deb-пакетами, скрипт для развертывания сайта...)
2. Создание и проверку резервных копий. Ага, бэкапы нужно проверять. Бывают битые бэкапы, бывает что система дает сбой и перестает делать бэкапы.
3. Нагрузочное тестирование, если у вас сайт или сервис с API. Полученную статистику нужно как-то анализировать. Можно встраивать проверки на соответствие [SLA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3).

## 5. Все проверки и инспекции должны быть пройдены

Это можно понять двумя способами:

1. Акцент на слово «пройдены». Достаточно очевидное правило — если тесты не проходят, значит код ошибочный (или сломались тесты).
2. Акцент на слово «все». Может так случиться, что разработчик просто закомментирует тест, который не проходит, если обнаруживаемую ошибку он пока что не собирается править.

Страховкой от таких ситуаций служат инструменты оценки покрытия кода. Оценка покрытия должна быть обязательным этапом автоматизированного построения. Тогда можно будет увидеть, что, например, все тесты проходят, но покрытие уменьшилось либо просто недостаточное.

Если вы практикуете TDD (а автор вопроса практикует, я точно знаю), то пункт 2 расширяется написанием новых тестов. Если тесты и тестируемый код отделены друг от друга, позаботьтесь о том, чтобы система CI брала то и другое из нужных веток.

## 6. Выполняйте закрытое построение

Под закрытым понимается *интеграционное* построение для целей тестирования. Авторы книги имеют в виду построение на своей рабочей машине, но нередко используется специальное тестовое окружение. Например, если вы пишете клиент-серверное приложение, то можно использовать специально выделенный сервер, на котором развертывается тестируемая версия.

В идеале построение производится на каждый коммит разработчика (а коммиты происходят часто). Это реализуется за счет связи между системой контроля версий и системой непрерывной интеграции (например, Jenkins или TeamCity). При обнаружении новой версии в вашей рабочей ветке система должна автоматически запускать построение (в это входит и компиляция и, когда необходимо, развертывание на тестовом контуре), следом за которым идут различные тесты.

Сервер непрерывной интеграции должен быть достаточно мощным, чтобы отрабатывать компиляцию хотя бы не медленнее, чем на собственной машине разработчика. Некоторые задачи в принципе нереализуемы на рабочей машине, например нагрузочное тестирование через WiFi тестирует только сам WiFi. Это также снимает распространенную проблему, когда код компилируется очень долго, а разработчик уходит гулять/есть/спать/домой.

## 7. Избегайте получения сбойного кода

Если коллега слил в dev сбойный код — не используйте его для дальнейшей работы (код, не коллегу). Если вы возьмете этот код и будете его дальше переделывать, вам обеспечено море веселья и какие-нибудь многосторонние слияния, когда коллега исправит ошибку и вам нужно будет интегрировать исправления в свой код.

Не используйте сбойный код даже если он общается с вашим кодом через какой-то интерфейс. Может оказаться, что вы написали какую-то заплатку для компенсации ошибки на той стороне. Потом ошибка будет исправлена и придется вырезать заплатку.

Конечно, это достаточно идеалистичное требование. Бывает, что ошибка обнаружена уже на бою, все о ней знают, но немедленной правки не предвидится. Тогда вам нужно будет писать заплатку, а потом договариваться об одновременных изменениях на разных сторонах.

Comment: `2. Не передавайте сбойный код`: Могу дополнить что существует такое понятие как отложенный коммит (https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/delayed_commit.html). Я пока не использовал, но думаю он поможет со вторым пунктом. Спасибо за крутой ответ, я не ожидал что будет так много клевых ответов, люблю SO :)

Comment: из моих вопросов никто не уйдет без награды ;)

Comment: @Onedev.Link отложенный коммит - это что-то вроде Gated Commit / Gated Check In. Его MS пытался пропихнуть в TFS 2010 - не уверен, взлетела фичас или нет.

Comment: @PashaPash полет нормальный :).

Answer (score 36):

Непрерывная интеграция подразумевает только сборку билдов. Мержи она никак не оговаривает.

У вас проблема совсем не не в том, что вы редко вливаете изменения в develop. У вас несколько смежных проблем, которые приводят к последствиям в виде крупных мержей.

1. Ваши разработчики редко вливают изменения из develop в feature branch-и. 
   Т.е. вы не решаете мерж-конфликты между двумя ветками по мере их появления, а откладываете "на потом". 
   Вот это "потом" и вылазит при попытке смержить. Не обязательно физически мержить изменения - git rerere умеет записывать результаты мержа без коммита.
2. Вы заводите ветки не по фичам, а по людям. У вас три девелопера, и они одновременно пишут три фичи? Сконцентрируйтесь на одной. Работа двух девелоперов на одной ветке - это нормально!
3. Вы используете относительно тяжеловесный процесс (git flow) на небольшом проекте (вас всего трое). Возможно, вам стоит посмотреть в сторону [GitHub Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/). Пуллреквесты на github сильно облегчат вам жизнь - тем, что в них есть явный индикатор немержабельности веток. И кроме того, TeamCity умеет собирать чек-билды на merge-ветках - результатах автомержа - так что вы будете видеть реальную картину.

Дополнение из комментариев:

GitHub, и как и многие  остальные системы с поддержкой PR, не просто проверяют возможность автомержа. Они реально проводят мерж, и создают новый head с именем вида merge/номер_pr. TeamСity подхватывает его и запускает билд. Т.е. проверяется

- возможен ли мерж вообще
- пройдут ли тесты если вы смержите (до того, как вы действительно смержили)

Это позволяет вовремя и автоматически(!) ловить изменения, которые не вызвали конфликты, но поломали тесты. Сейчас же вы ради этого мержите (редко, вручную) и ждете билда (который по сути тоже запускаете вручную, кнопкой push).

Основная идея непрерывной интеграции - это действительно *непрерывная* автоматическая интеграция. Если у вас TeamCity используется только ради проверки ручного мержа - то он вам не нужен. Он просто экономит вам одно нажатие кнопки раз в пару дней.

Билды надо собирать на каждый коммит (коммитать и пушить часто и по чуть-чуть - вы же все равно в отдельный бранчах работаете) и на каждый потенциальный мерж - т.е. действительно непрерывно.

Comment: Спасибо! Мы, действительно, "откладываем на потом" мерж-конфликты. Ветки у нас по фичам, но так как каждый программист работает над своей фичей со вторым пунктом вы тоже угадали. GitHub я к огромному сожалению использовать не могу, мы код держим на своих серверах. Я хочу понять какой профит я могу получить от сервера непрерывной интеграции. Сейчас он за меня выполняет все тесты, это круто, но я не вижу другого его использования. Какой смысл в чек-билдах? Проверить что merge успешен и в результате все тесты прошли? Можете рассказать о том как сервер непрерывной интеграции упрощает вам жизнь?

Comment: Эту награду я вручу @MarkShevchenko, а вас награжу через неделю большими баллами :)

Comment: @Onedev.Link да мне как бы баллы и не нужны. на своих серверах можно использовать любую другую оболочку с поддержкой пуллреквестов (gitlab, tfs, их много). про пользу интеграции сейчас напишу

Comment: @Onedev.Link дописал. кстати, а почему у вас так редко коммитается код (раз в пару дней). И зачем вы держите исходники у себя (гитхаб стоит копейки)?

Comment: Баллы не нужны, но будут :) `gitlab` добавил в закладки, в ближайшее время заценю. Исходники держим у себя исходя из решения тимлида, когда стану тимлидом перемещу репозиторий на гитхаб. Коммиты, конечно, происходят чаще, но merge в `develop` субъективно достаточно поздний.

Comment: сервер непрерывной интеграции каждый коммит разных веток мержит в develop? В таком случае считаются ситуации когда коммит ломает функционал ненормальными? Что делать если надо переписать модуль? (А это много коммитов, в течении которых функционал и тесты могут не работать)

Comment: не сервер непрерывной интеграции мержит ветки. ветки мержит Github /gitlab - причем не мержит *в* develop, а просто создает мерж-ветку - в которой лежит то, что *лежало бы* в develop, если бы вы на самом деле смержили туда изменения. эдакий автоматический предсказатель успешности мержа. т.е. реального мержа еще нет - а результат билда на этом мерже - уже есть :)

Comment: если надо переписать модуль - значит надо создавать PR как можно раньше. или просто регулярно мержить. если честно - я не понимаю в чем проблема регулярно подмерживать dev/master в свою ветку, хотя бы с rerere. это же прямо в интересах девелопера - ведь именно он в конце-концов напорется на 100 конфликтов

Comment: а то, что тесты на ветке PR будут красными - ну ок, это не критично - все же понимают, что это еще не готовый функционал - тесты можно просто замьютить. главное чтобы девелопер был в курсе, что тесты упали - вдруг он думал, что они пройдут, а тут сюрприз!

Comment: супер, спасибо, отличное введение в тему.

Comment: Кстати, а GitLab производит автомерж? Что-то я не могу в нем найти эту фичу.

Comment: @NickVolynkin они точно проверяют возможность автомержа - что тяжело сделать без собственно попытки мержа. напишите им в саппорт, вдруг ответят :)

Comment: Кстати, про `merge/номер_pr` - как получить доступ к этому? Пытался сделать `git checkout remote/merge/1` - безуспешно, да и среди веток его не видно.

Comment: "Непрерывная интеграция подразумевает только сборку билдов." -- это [CI theatre](https://www.gocd.org/2017/05/16/its-not-CI-its-CI-theatre.html). Одно из определений CI подразумевает, что разработчики часто интегрируют свой код в основную ветку, что, естественно, ведет к мержам.

Comment: @andreycha да, это подразумевается тем определением CI, которое появилось во времена, когда мейнстримом было вести одну ветку (trunk), коммитать прямо в нее, часто, и под мержами тогда подразумевались локальные мержи при svn up, а не мержи бранчей друг с другом. С тех пор появились DVCS, вошли бранчи и пуллреквесты и общепринятое определение CI изменилось. По вашей ссылке заявляется, что для тру-CI -нужен именно Trunk based development...brings the pain forward rather than storing it up for *merges*, *code reviews* or delaying releases. Это немного устаревшее определение CI для 2017-го года :)

Comment: @andreycha т.е. заявлять "checking into master at least once daily", "Everyone Commits To the Mainline Every Day", или "это не CI", ссылаясь на оригинальный термин от Фаулера, можно. Но термин поплыл из-за распространения CI-серверов. GitFlow - не тру-CI. GitLab, GitHub flow - не тру-CI. Тестировщики - не QA. Найм DevOps инженеров не имеет отношения к DevOps. MVC - не тот, что у Фаулера. Под паттерном репозиторий подразумевают вообще черт знает что. Современную разработку заполонили дилетанты, которые делают все неправильно. Такие дела :(

Comment: Trunk-based development -- это всего лишь один из способов. Ничто не мешает использовать фича-бранчи. Нужно только не мариновать их неделями, а пытаться разбивать задачи на более мелкие и вливаться в основную ветку чаще (понятно, что для этого тоже есть исключения).

Comment: В общем, я хотел сказать, что CI все-таки не только про билды, но и про интеграцию кода.

Answer (score 30):

В похожей ситуации гугление подсказало: она возникает из-за того, что технические средства — а именно git — не заменяют организации совместной работы.

В частности, проблемные слияния возникают из-за того, что два и более независимых разработчика вносят существенные изменения в одни и те же файлы. Косвенно это может свидетельствовать о проблемах с архитектурой проекта. Обычно о том, что принцип единой ответственности нарушен в одном или нескольких классах, и эти классы приходится править разным людям по разным поводам.

Это может также свидетельствовать, что проект в самом начале, и идёт шлифовка той части, которая называется *ядром*.

Соответственно, вариантами решений будут:

1. Обсуждение и утверждение регламента совместной разработки (кто и что, когда и как может менять).
2. Рефакторинг ядра — разбиение его не более мелкие независимые классы.
3. Аккуратное распределение работ между участниками команды.

Сервер непрерывной интеграции не решает проблему слияний. Слияния это специфика Mercurial/Git, распределённых систем версионирования. Сервер непрерывной интеграции позволяет контролировать появление проблем интеграции, которые могут возникнуть и в CVS, и в SVN, и даже при обмене файлами на дискетах.

Comment: Да, верно, а сервер непрерывной интеграции зачем нужен?

Comment: @Onedev.Link Обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, полезный ответ! У нас пока "ядро", но всё-равно думаю большую часть проблем действительно доставляет нарушения SRP.

Answer (score 14):

Постараюсь ответить на ваш вопрос
Хочу услышать как в ваших проектах организована работа с сервером непрерывной интеграции. Как вы бы организовали нашу работу исходя из текущих условий?

Вот список используемого софта (за исключением студий для разработок) Выбор SVN или GIT не критичен, это дело вкуса. Данный пример реализован у нас на предприятии.

**TortoiseSVN** — это бесплатный Windows-клиент с открытыми исходным кодом для системы управления версиями Apache™ Subversion®. 
Статус каждого версированного файла и папки отображается при помощи маленькой пометки поверх основного значка. Таким образом, вы сразу можете видеть состояние вашей рабочей копии. CVS отслеживает только историю отдельных файлов, тогда как Subversion реализует «виртуальную» версионную файловую систему, которая отслеживает изменения в целых деревьях папок во времени.

**Redmine** — открытое серверное веб-приложение для управления проектами и задачами (в том числе для отслеживания ошибок). Redmine написан на Ruby и представляет собой приложение на основе широко известного веб-фреймворка Ruby on Rails. Распространяется согласно GNU General Public License.
Данный продукт предоставляет следующие возможности:

- ведение нескольких проектов;
- гибкая система доступа, основанная на ролях;
- система отслеживания ошибок;
- диаграммы Ганта и календарь;
- ведение новостей проекта, документов и управление файлами;
- оповещение об изменениях с помощью RSS-потоков и электронной почты;
- вики для каждого проекта;
- форумы для каждого проекта;
- учёт временных затрат;
- настраиваемые произвольные поля для инцидентов, временных затрат, проектов и пользователей;
- лёгкая интеграция с системами управления версиями (SVN, CVS, Git, Mercurial, Bazaar и Darcs);
- создание записей об ошибках на основе полученных писем;
- поддержка множественной аутентификации LDAP;
- возможность самостоятельной регистрации новых пользователей;
- многоязычный интерфейс (в том числе русский);
- поддержка СУБД MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, Oracle.

**Jenkins.**

Как прежде отмечалось необходимо контролировать работоспособ-ность написанных программных модулей при внесении изменений в дей-ствующий проект, тестировать их на разных платформах, сигнализировать об ошибках при построении, для этого используется Jenkins.

Инструмент непрерывной интеграции. Запускается в контейнере сервлетов (расширяет функциональные возможности сервера), таких как Apache Tomcat или GlassFish. Поддерживает инструментарий для работы с разными системами контроля версий, в нашем случае Subversion, может собирать проекты, а также исполнять shell-скрипты и команды Windows. Автономная сборка проектов на сервере Jenkins может быть назначена на разные события, например, производиться по расписанию, либо стартовать, когда другая сборка уже собрана, либо при запросе определённого URL, выкачивая перед этим все обновления из svn, и собирая их на всех операционных системах автономно.

Плюсы использования Jenkins:

- Когда кто-то ломает проект, вы узнаете об этом сразу, что позволяет
  быстро устранить проблему;
- Вы можете автоматизировать прогон тестов, развертывать приложения на
  тестовых серверах, выполнять проверку code style и тому подобные
  вещи;
- Также в Jenkins можно хранить собранные deb-пакеты, отчеты о прогоне
  тестов или Javadoc/Doxygen/EDoc-документацию;

Данное решение, которое я вам предложу настроено приблизительно на 15-20 программистов. Все программисты соблюдают одно простое правило. "Перед коммитом скачай Update, проверь совместимость с твоими изменениями и вливай." Так как проект большой. Сделано всего две ветки.

1) Первая. В нее вливаются все изменения разработчиков. И каждый божий  день Jenkins непрерывно ее интегрирует. В случае если-что, то пошло не так, то он отправляет уведомление тому, кто поломал сборку. Сборка к стати производиться на множество ОС.

2) Тестовая. Как правило каждую неделю она мержится с первой. А в течении недели производит сборки под разные ОС. Тестировщики ее пытаются нагнуть.

3) За редким исключением выделяется отдельная ветка для разработчика. Это делается в случае, если он начинает вносить серьезные изменения в ядро или библиотеку общего пользования. После того, как ему удастся смержить две ветки, он получает разрешение на коммит.

Comment: Почему SVN, а не GIT/HG?

Comment: @PashaPash Спасибо за замечание. Это особого значения не имеет. GIT или SVN. Я привел пример, как реализовано у нас на предприятии. Внесу изменения в ответ

Comment: я не против SVN, просто мне интересно - почему у вас именно SVN используется? почему не перешли на GIT до сих пор.

Comment: т.е. например у нас соскочили с SVN как только пришлось работать с ветками. почему вы выбрали решение "одна ветка" при таком количестве людей? вызывает это какие-то сложности, или все ок. если все о - то как ваши разработчики умудряются не толкаться локтями при регулярных коммитах?

Comment: и что вы делаете, если кто-то поломал сборку? не апдейтите локальные копии? откатываете изменения?

Comment: На данный момент переход затруднен в связи с большим штатом сотрудников. Не все быстро обучаемы.  Тут сидят программисты которым за 50. Попробовать внедрить данный продукт управления версиями создаст много проблем с персоналом нежели с проектом. А текущий TortoiseSVN не на много уступает GitHub.

Comment: В случае поломки сборки jenkins отправляет уведомления непосредственно тому, кто это сделал, и собственно чей код он покарежил. Как правило в данном случае решение принимается вовлеченными сотрудниками оперативно. Либо откат изменений, либо быстрый фикс

Comment: Основное преимущесто гита - дешевые ветки (отсутствие простоя при поломанном билде "общей" ветки) и дешевый мерж. Это тяжело оценить без попытки перехода, или осознания текущих проблему. Мы в такой же ситуации сначала перешли на HG - там по сравнению с SVN всего две дополнительных кнопки (push/pull), и интерфейс у клиента - TortoiseHG - совпадает. а потом уже на гит. в любом случае - спасибо что поделились деталями процесса! :)

Comment: @PashaPash По поводу без попытки оценить переход. Я это прекрасно понимаю) Уже ни раз поднимал данную тему на совещаниях. Но проблема не в машинах)))

Comment: @NewSheriff спасибо за ответ! Можете сказать примерно как часто у вас осуществляются коммиты? Проверка совместимости изменений выполняется тестами на локальной машине разработчика?

Comment: @Onedev.Link В среднем от 5 до 15 коммитов в день. Сотрудник делает железно один комит, раз в три дня. Пред выходными и отпусками коммиты запрещены.  Как правило локально разработчик проверяет только ту часть, которую предположительно он может коснуться. В случае если, что-то пошло не так Jenkins присылает уведомления в котором содержится Какая сборка сломалась, Кто сломал, Кому сломали, место бага(в идеальном случае).

Comment: @NewSheriff Пробовали рассмотреть вариант с несколькими ветками под фичи и мержем в основную? В таком случае не пришлось бы запрещать коммиты перед выходными. Я думаю коммиты получаются большими по размеру, какое время примерно затрачивают разработчики на проверку совместимости?

Comment: @Onedev.Link "Запрещено" имеется ввиду негласное правило. Просто удаленно проблемы решить немного труднее.
 
Время зависит от того, как много проектов нужно отбилдить)

В основном не больше 15 минут. Так же хорошим тоном считается писать модульные тесты, которые не дают всякому г*вну просочится.  Если возникли ошибки, то уже от сложности ошибки зависит, быстро ли ты сделаешь коммит. 

Заведено следующее, даже если еще не готово. наполняешь свой код заглушками, делаешь коммит.  Большие изменения стараемся избегать. А так хотя бы будет известно, что ты трогаешь и как.

Comment: @Onedev.Link У нас очень хорошо реализована часть модульного тестирования. Любые изменения хочешь ты или нет, как-нибудь да и проходят через тесты. И ты каждый раз при сборке знаешь, где косяк. Сделать кривой коммит трудно.

Answer (score 10):

Википедия считает так:

> Непрерывная интеграция (CI, англ. Continuous Integration) — это практика разработки программного обеспечения, которая заключается в выполнении частых автоматизированных сборок проекта для скорейшего выявления и решения интеграционных проблем. В обычном проекте, где над разными частями системы разработчики трудятся независимо, стадия интеграции является заключительной. Она может непредсказуемо задержать окончание работ. Переход к непрерывной интеграции позволяет снизить трудоёмкость интеграции и сделать её более предсказуемой за счет наиболее раннего обнаружения и устранения ошибок и противоречий.

Короче говоря, это выход обновлений по расписанию. Причём достаточно часто и автоматизированно (например, через Makefile)

Comment: Сборка - это не "релиз обновления". Это просто сборка - build + прогон тестов (если они есть).

Comment: @PashaPash Это я и имел ввиду