# Что такое Опыт работы в системе CI/CD

Tags: непрерывная-интеграция

Вопрос теоретический, что есть такое контейнер CI/CD и у некоторых работодателей требуется опыт работы в системе CI/CD? Что имеется ввиду?

Comment: Частично дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470453/

Comment: Я не думаю что  это дубликат. я смотрел что есть тут по этому вопросу, хочется увидеть опыт и ответы людей, которые с этим работают.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CI - непрерывная интеграция, упрощенно говоря, это подход к разработке, при котором изменения в исходном коде часто отправляются на сервер и автоматизированно собираются и тестируются. CD (непрерывное развертывание), это аналогично, только помимо сборки код автоматизированно развертывается для конечного использования (например, выкладывается на веб-сервер для веб приложений, или пакуется в установочный пакет целевой ОС для десктопных приложений). Контейнер CI - видимо, просто Docker Container, в котором осуществляются эти действия, если используется [Docker](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/architecture/microservices/container-docker-introduction/docker-defined). Теория по CI описана по большей части здесь: [Что такое непрерывная интеграция?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470453/)

В качестве практического примера CI можно привести использование GitHub Actions для автоматизированного построения приложения .NET Core.

Создадим репозиторий GitHub, и заполним его тестовым проектом C# .NET Core

Перейдем на вкладку GitHub Actions

[image: GitHub Actions]

Для проекта с кодом на C# система автоматически предлагает создать Workflow .NET Core. Нажмем кнопку "Set up this workflow". Система предложит создать шаблонный файл конфигурации dotnetcore.yml:

```
name: .NET Core

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 2.2.108
    - name: Build with dotnet
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release
```

Здесь мы видим два стандартных шага: установка .NET Core SDK нужной версии и запуск сборки с помощью команды dotnet build. Добавим два своих шага: архивацию результатов сборки и запуск получившегося приложения:

```
name: .NET Core

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 2.2.108
    - name: Build with dotnet
      run: dotnet build CoreTest.sln --configuration Release
    - name: Archive build results
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
      with:
          name: Output
          path: NetCoreTest/bin/Release/
    - name: Run
      run: |        
        dotnet NetCoreTest/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/NetCoreTest.dll
```

Зафиксируем результат. Теперь после отправки каждого изменения в репозиторий мы можем автоматически видеть результаты сборки:

[image: build results]

Эти результаты фигурируют как проверка для Pull request (на вкладке Checks) - можно сделать проверку обязательной, и тогда нельзя будет выполнить слияние изменений, если сборка проходит с ошибкой. Серьезное преимущество в том, что мы всегда можем убедится, что приложение собирается допустим на Linux, даже не имея локальной машины с этой ОС. Под капотом в данном случае не Docker, а виртуальные машины Azure, так что контейнера CI нет (есть виртуальное окружение CI).

Пример репозитория с настроенным CI: https://github.com/MSDN-WhiteKnight/CoreTest

Comment: Отличный комментарий. Спасибо теперь понятно, вот мне не хватало как раз момента с гитом,как это все связано.

Answer (score 5):

Неизвестно, что имеется в виду работодателями, когда они требуют опыт работы с CI/CD. Обычный разработчик должен уметь работать с git или mercurial, больше ничего. Непосредственно интеграцию и развёртывание делают серверные скрипты, которые настраивают либо системные администраторы, либо опытные разработчики команды.

Разобраться с тем, как и что можно настраивать — дело нескольких дней. Можно что-то такое написать самому, опираясь на так называемые *хуки* систем контроля версий, но обычно сейчас используют билд-серверы с GUI.

Если речь заходит о *контейнере* CI/CD, то скорее всего имеют в виду Docker. Очень удобное решение, которое сильно упростило то, что скрывается за буквой D в CD, то есть *развёртывание*.

Пример. Чтобы убедиться, что новый код ничего не сломает, после сборки проекта и прогона *модульных тестов* можно развернуть контур интеграционного тестирования. Для этого надо запустить несколько контейнеров Docker с образами баз и новой сборкой. На тестовом контуре можно запускать скрипты, которые проверят, что система работает в сборе — от торчащего наружу API, и до сидящей внутри базы данных.

Ещё раз повторю, что никакой серьёзной магии за этим нет, всё осваивается за несколько дней.

На что хотел бы обратить внимание, так это на культуру *совместной разработки*. Выучить команды git не очень сложно, хотя они и запутаны немного. Гораздо сложнее приобрести полезные для командной работы привычки.

- **Короткие ветки**. Неопытные разработчики часто сидят в своих ветках в течение нескольких дней. За это время код успевает убежать далеко вперёд. Даже если они забирают изменения, вероятность больших слияний возрастает. Правило здесь такое: разбивать задачи так, чтобы каждую задачу можно было решить в течение нескольких часов. Лучше не оставлять открытых задач на завтра.
- **Микрофиксации**, то есть micro commits. Каждый commit должен содержать немного файлов и его назначение должно описываться одним предложением. Это нужно для удобного code review. Во время работы у вас часто получается, что часть файлов содержит решение задачи, а часть — рефакторинг. git позволяет сначала добавить одни изменённые файлы в первый commit, и затем другие во второй.
- **Названия фиксаций**. При выполнении git commit обязательно заполнять комментарий осмысленным текстом. Многие не делают, и зря. Плохо для code review.

Вот эти правила осваиваются долго и, как правило, сопровождаются чем-нибудь неприятным: сломанными слияниями, трудными обзорами кода, разборками в команде. Но когда всё это позади, работать становится проще и быстрее.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, получается это больше работа правильная с гитхабом.

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch, не обязательно с гитхабом. CI/CD может быть настроен локально, без гитхаба.